# Resistance of a frustum, or a pyramid cut from top

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, physics

We know that Resistance is given by:
$$R = \dfrac{\rho L}{A}$$

The figure of Resistance is like this, $L$ is perpendicular distance between $A_1$ and $A_2$

[image]

I assumed that the area change linearly, so Area $A(x)$ will be:

$$A = A_1 + \left(\dfrac{A_2-A_1}{L}\right)x$$

Using this, $dR$ will be:

$$\dfrac{\rho dx}{A_1 + \left(\dfrac{A_2-A_1}{L}\right)x}$$

Integrating this, I get:

$$R = \dfrac{\rho L\ln\left(\dfrac{A_2}{A_1}\right)}{A_2 - A_1}$$

But answer given in problem book is $$R = \dfrac{\rho L}{\sqrt{A_1A_2}}$$

Where do I go wrong? I am confused with this for long time. Thank You!

Comment: This is not really a *on-topic* question for Math SE....

Comment: how? is it not allowed? I want to know whether my approach is correct

Comment: Maybe ( I didn't check that ) " $\underline{\mbox{the area change linearly}}$ " isn't correct. Check that point.

Comment: The length of side changes linearly, not area.

Comment: should observe the inverse square law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MaxPayne pointed out, area varies quadratically with side length, which in turn varies linearly with $x$. The right formula for $A$ is thus:
$$
A=\left( \sqrt{A_1}+ {\sqrt{A_2}-\sqrt{A_1}\over L}x \right)^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I understand my mistake, Indeed this is true.